# Problems with virtualbox 4.1.2r73507

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have problem with starting virtualbox on my Windows7 desktop machine. Sometimes, Oracle VirtualBox manager just won't start. In task manager I can see processes VBoxSVC.exe and VirtualBox.exe, but no GUI to start host machine.
When this happens, all I can do is restart (or log of) from computer until GUI appear.
What to do?

Just to clarify I can kill VirtualBox.exe in task manager but I can't kill VBoxSVC.exe, and that's why I have to log off or restart machine.

Tnx.

---

I can't restart VBoxSVC exe from services.msc. Why? Well There are no services with that name in list.

Answer (score 1):

I cant give you a reason for why the VirtualBox is not starting without knowing specifics of the environment. But instead of restarting the system each time have you tried killing the process and restarting the service.....will save you some good time.

Comment: Well I can kill VirtualBox.exe proces, but I can't kill the other one VBoxSVC.exe. And that's why I have to log off or restart...

Comment: cant you restart that using services.msc ->VBoxSVC.exe -> Restart ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I don't seem to see any services in my services.msc that has anything to do with VirtualBox